# Haskell functor implementation dealing with "BOX"?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory, category-abstractions

In Category theory, Functor concept is as the below:

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/functor

[image]

In Haskell, `Functor` type can be expressed as:

`fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html

and I could see the both really corresponds well.

However, once we actually try to implement this Functor concept down to a code, it seems impossible to define `F` or `fmap` as simple as the diagram shown above.

In fact, there is a famous article about Functor/Monad.

[Functors, Applicatives, And Monads In Pictures](http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html)

Here,

> Simple enough. Lets extend this by saying that any value can be in a context. For now you can think of a context as a box that you can put a value in:

[image]

or

> Here's what is happening behind the scenes when we write fmap (+3) (Just 2):

[image]

What I always feel about `Functor` is the **concept of Functor in category theory** and **concept of wrap&unwrap to/from "BOX"** does not match well.

Quesion Point 1.

`fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html

Where is the actual implementation of wrap&unwrap to/from "BOX" in Haskell?

Question Point 2.

Why the **concept of Functor in category theory** and **concept of wrap&unwrap to/from "BOX"** does not match well?

EDIT:

Even for `IO` functor, during the composition process, `f` is unwrapped:

```js
  // f is unwrapped in composition process
  const compose = g => f => x => g(f(x));

  const fmap = compose;

  const print = a => () => console.log(a);
  
  // safely no side-effect
  const todo = fmap(print("bar"))(print("foo"));

  //side effect
  todo(undefined); // foo bar

  // with pipleline operator (ES.next)
  //
  //  const todo = print("foo")
  //    |> fmap(print("bar"))
  //    |> fmap(print("baz"));

  //  todo(undefined); // foo bar baz
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We like one question per post, it helps future learners find what they are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that, however, some question can be divided to multiple  points, and I think it should not be presented separately for future learners. This is one question.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard and Please do not down vote after your read my disagreement of your personal opinion. I believe what I did and said is nothing wrong. To be fair, only my mistake is to have written Question,2, and let you comment like that. I modified as Question Point.

Comment: @smooth_write you presume to know who downvoted you and why. That's a bad look.

Answer (score 5):

The ideas from category theory are so abstract that anyone who tries to provide an intuitive introduction runs the risk of simplifying concepts to the point where they may confuse people. As the author of [an article series in this space](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/10/04/from-design-patterns-to-category-theory), I can testify that it doesn't take much imprecise language before someone misunderstands the text.

I don't know the particular article, but I believe that it may exhibit the same trait. The wrap/unwrap metaphor fits a substantial subset of functors (e.g. `Maybe`, `[]`, `Either l`, etc.), but not all.

Famously, you're [not supposed to unwrap `IO`](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2020/06/08/the-io-container); that is by design. At that point, the wrap/unwrap metaphor falls apart. It's no longer valid in the face of `IO`.

Indeed, the concepts don't match. I'd say that the wrap/unwrap metaphor may be useful as an introduction, but as always, there's a limit to how much you can stretch a metaphor.

How are the `Functor` instances implemented? Most introductions to Haskell will show you how to write `fmap` for `Maybe`, `[]`, and a few other types. It can also be a good exercise to implement them yourself, if you get the chance.

GHC and its ecosystem is open source, so you can always look at the source code if you wonder how a particular instance is implemented.

Again, `IO` is a big exception to the rule. As far as I understand it, its `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Monad`, etc. instances aren't implemented in (Safe) Haskell, but rather in a small core of unsafe code (C or C++, I believe) that constitutes the core of the compiler and/or runtime environment. There's no (explicit, visible, safe) unwrapping going on with `IO`. I think it's more helpful to think of `IO`'s `Functor` instance as the *structure-preserving map* that it is.

For more details about the correspondence between category theory and Haskell, I recommend [Bartosz Milewski's article series on the topic](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface).

Comment: Thank you! First of all I'm happy you answered my question because I have read your article series as well as Bartosz Milewski's (his YouTube,too).

Comment: For `IO`, I've noticed it's sort of hard to implement, however, eventually, I discovered it's just a composition of `to-do` functions (in Haskell, it's called as `action`). For wrap/unwrap metaphor, since function composition is `f => g => x => x |> f |> g` , `f` is unwrapped during the process in a sense, without actual side-effect.

Comment: @smooth_writing There's really no unwrapping going on with `IO`. There's no *safe* function with the type `IO a -> a`. Unlike `Maybe`, or `[]`, or `Either`, you can't pattern-match to 'get at' the value in the `IO` box. What you *can* do is to *map* a morphism `a -> b` into a morphism in the 'world' of `IO`: `IO a -> IO b`.

Comment: @smooth_writing That doesn't look like Haskell code...(?)

Comment: now, I posted the final code (EDIT of my question). It's a JS snippet, and as you can see function composition does unwrap `f`, and until we trigger 
the "final unwrap", the `to-do` or `actions` is safely without side-effect.

Comment: Of course, `IO` in Haskell is basically `State` Functor/Monad, However, here we discuss Category theory and programming in general, and I discovered `IO` is simply function composition, and unwrapping of function exists during the composition...

Comment: @smooth_writing Sorry, I don't understand JavaScript... It looks like you define `fmap` as composition. If so, that's not `IO`; that's the *reader* functor.

Comment: Correct, sir. However, the point is `IO` in Haskell is `Actions` chain, and that is fundamentally a function composition. Please excuse me to repeat, but function composition includes "unwrap `f` " in a sense.

Comment: `g` is unwrapped, but no side effect : `f . g  = \ x -> f (g x)`

Comment: @smooth_writing What do you mean by `Actions` chain? I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing any longer... The way I interpret *unwrapping* in the context of the 'box illustration' is that there's a (possibly partial) function `f a -> a`. Such a function doesn't exist for `IO`. There's no (safe) way you can unwrap the `a` from `IO a`, apply some pure function to it, and put it back into `IO`. AFAICT, though, that's what the illustration implies.

Comment: It’s worth emphasising that `IO a` doesn’t *contain* an `a` at all, so it’s a bit misleading to talk about “the” `a` in an `IO a`. Even `unsafePerformIO` doesn’t “extract” anything, it just *hides* the action. `getDirectoryContents "/Users/jpurdy"` is an action that *fetches* the list of filenames in my home directory, just like `ls` is a program that does so; the `IO [FilePath]` returned from `getDirectoryContents` is the “program” itself, not a `[FilePath]` somehow “tagged” with the fact that it came from `IO`. This is an important aspect of Haskell: `main :: IO ()` is a pure value.

Comment: After the talk, I noticed that Identity functor, for instance, we can define `unit = a => f => unit(f(a))`, and in this way, we don't need "unwrap" the context. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the arrows in the picture. There is **no way** to go from the functor level back to the non-functor level. You would need a function that goes from `F(x)` to `x`, but - as you can see - none is defined.

There are specific functors (like `Maybe`) that offer the "unwrapping" functionality, but such feature is always an add-on, it's delivered *on top* of something being a functor. For example you might say: `Maybe` is a functor, and also it has an interesting property: there's a partial function that maps `Maybe X` to X, and which reverses `pure`.

**UPDATE (after the additional question appeared)** The concepts of a box and a functor simply don't match. Also, as far as I know, no good metaphor for a functor (or a monad, or an applicative) has been found - and not for the lack of trying. It's not even surprising: most abstractions lack good metaphors, precisely because abstractions and metaphors are polar opposites (in some way).

Abstraction strips a concept to its core, leaving only the barest essentials. Metaphor on the other hand, extends a concept, widens the semantic space, suggests more meaning. When I say: "your eyes have the color of chocolate", I am abstracting a notion of a "color". But I also metaphorically associate the eyes and chocolate: I suggest that they have more in common than just the color: silky texture, sweetness, pleasure - all those concepts are present, although none were named. If I said "your eyes have the color of excrement" the abstraction used would be exactly the same - but the metaphorical meaning: very different. I would not say it even to a logician, even though a logician would technically understand that the sentence is not offensive.

When on auto-pilot, most humans think in metaphors, not abstractions. Care must be taken when explaining the latter in terms of the former, because the meanings will spill over. When you hear "a box", the autopilot in your head tells you that you can put stuff in and get stuff out. Functor is not like that. So the metaphor is misleading.

Functor embodies an abstraction of a... box or a wrapper, but one that allows us to work on their contents WITHOUT ever unwrapping it. This lack of unwrapping is exactly the thing which makes functors interesting: otherwise `fmap` would just be a syntactic sugar for unwrapping, applying a function and wrapping the results up. Studying functors lets us understand how much is possible without unwrapping values - and, what's even better and more enlightening, it lets us understand what is impossible without unwrapping. The steps which lead up to applicatives, arrows and monads show us how to overcome some of the limitations by allowing additional operationsm but stukk **without ever allowing unwrapping**, because if we allowed unwrapping, the steps would make no sense (i.e. become trivial).

Comment: Thanks, in fact, yes, I already noticed that, and I should have mention the first part of your answer. Although, that's not exactly what I am fundamentally asking, as a supplement of my Quesiion, +1.

Comment: @smooth_writing: had a bit of time, wrote an essay :-) TLDR: there's no unwrap. The whole point is that there's no unwrap. Therefore box sucks big way as a functor metaphor. As do all metaphors, when applied to abstracts.

Comment: Thanks, but as you have earlier mentioned, without morphism from `F(x)` to `x` , isn't it impossible to implement Functor? Currently, I think the functor diagram is just a type result of implementation, and more or less, we need to go back and forth, which corresponds to Box unwrap&wrap with Lambda calculus

Comment: @smooth_writing No! The whole point, repeated over and over, is that a functor DOES NOT HAVE A `F(x) -> x`. The diagram is correct - it's not an "interpretation", "implementation" or "side effect". Functors are not meant to be "unwrapped". The very notion of a value leaving a functor is meaningless. It's not a box - it's a black hole. A magician's hat that makes things disappear. A one-way ticket to another dimension. Now if something is BOTH a functor and a candy, you can unwrap it and eat it. But that's because it's a candy, not because it's a functor.

Comment: @smooth_writing take a list of people. How do you "unwrap" them to a single person? See? there's no symmetry here. Wrapping a single person into a list is well defined, unwrapping is not. Wrapping an `x` into a `Maybe` is well defined, but generic unwrapping is impossible to write, because there's no way to get an `x` instance for a `Nothing`. This interesting philosophical fact, this lack of symmetry between wrapping and unwrapping - is exactly what makes functor a functor. So it's better to embrace it than to rebel against it...

Comment: After the talk, I noticed that Identity functor, for instance, we can define `unit = a => f => unit(f(a))`, and in this way, we don't need "unwrap" the context. Thanks anyway.